# Having problems generating a keystore (Java)

Tags: java, android, keystore, keytool

I am trying to publish my first Android application, and therefore need to sign the app with a keystore.

At first everything goes well.  I type the following into the command prompt:

```
keytool –genkey –v –keystore testKeystore.keystore –alias testKeystore –keyalg RSA –validity 10000
```

I answer the several questions that follow, but after the last question, I get the following error

keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: testKeystore.keystore [Access is denied]

Maybe I am doing some silly mistake, but I have followed several guides on the internet on how to make a keystore, and I thought that was all there was to it?

Comment: Mayby most obviuos one: you don't have right to write to in given directory?

Where do you want to save these testKeystore.keystore file? What operating system you use?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse, you can create a new keystore in the export wizard.  Double click on your android manifiest file, then select the 'Use the Export Wizard' link.

Answer (score 0):

use this command

keytool -genkeypair -alias  -keystore  -storepass  -validity 760 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=, OU=, O=, L=Bangalore, ST=Karnataka, C=91" -keypass changeit